# Create login with SID as string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logins

I'm trying to create a login as follows:

`CREATE LOGIN [Test] WITH PASSWORD='Test123', SID=SID_BINARY(N'S-1-5-21-408552231-458724953-3089381293-513')`

But no matter what it looks like SID only accepts a binary input, no subqueries or anything else really.

`Incorrect syntax near 'SID'.`

Is there a way to create a login with SID with a string?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3362/map-between-sql-server-sids-and-windows-sids/ <--- not a solution, just a warning that this is messy territory. I wrote a function that does the opposite of what you'll ultimately need (my function takes a 0x... binary value and outputs the S-1... string... you need to build a dynamic SQL statement that generates a 0x value that is correct and accepted by CREATE LOGIN based on the S-1... string you have).

Comment: Also see [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/175271/1186) which has an answer by Solomon that includes a reference to his SQLCLR library that includes a function to map in both directions.

Comment: Here are some functions to do that https://forum.mibuso.com/discussion/48606/find-sql-user-name-with-quot-windows-login-quot-sid

Answer (score 4):

A funny thing about `SID_BINARY()` - it outputs `binary(28)` in this case, whereas `CREATE LOGIN` expects `binary(16)`. As Solomon points out, and adding here so there is no ambiguity, this means **there is no way to create a SQL Server SID based on - or that can map to - the Windows identifier you posted in your question.** You want `CREATE LOGIN ... FROM Windows` for that.

Your first problem, though, is the syntax error. The reason you're getting that is because you can't use expressions in a `CREATE LOGIN` statement, and it doesn't take variables either, so you need to construct dynamic SQL.

I tried to use all 28 bytes as follows:

```
DECLARE @sid_in varchar(100);
SET @sid_in = 'S-1-5-21-408552231-458724953-3089381293-513';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE LOGIN [Test] WITH PASSWORD = N''foo'',
  SID = ' + CONVERT(varchar(64), SID_BINARY(@sid_in), 1) + N';';

PRINT @sql;
```

Yielded:

```
CREATE LOGIN [Test] WITH PASSWORD = N'foo', 
  SID = 0x01050000000000051500000027035A185996571BAD3724B801020000;
```

Of course, executing that SQL yielded an error, as I expected:

> Msg 15419, Level 16, State 1
>   
> Supplied parameter sid should be binary(16).

So then I wondered if truncating to 16 bytes would work. I thought this was incompatible because losing 12 bytes should be a problem:

```
DECLARE @sid_in varchar(100), @sid_out varchar(100);
SET @sid_in = 'S-1-5-21-408552231-458724953-3089381293-513';

SELECT original = SID_BINARY(@sid_in);
SELECT trimmed  = CONVERT(binary(16), SID_BINARY(@sid_in));
```

Results:

```
original
----------------------------------------------------------
0x01050000000000051500000027035A185996571BAD3724B801020000

trimmed
0x01050000000000051500000027035A18
```

But then I tried it, and it (kind of) worked. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @sid_in varchar(100);
SET @sid_in = 'S-1-5-21-408552231-458724953-3089381293-513';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE LOGIN [Test] WITH PASSWORD = N''foo'',
  SID = ' + CONVERT(varchar(64), CONVERT(binary(16),SID_BINARY(@sid_in)), 1) + N';';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

And to prove that trimming those 12 bytes off has little effect:

```
DECLARE @sid_in varchar(100);
SET @sid_in = 'S-1-5-21-408552231-458724953-3089381293-513';

SELECT SUSER_SNAME(CONVERT(binary(16),SID_BINARY(@sid_in)));
```

Results:

```
----
Test
```

This just means that you can write your code in such a way that you can still get to the right login given the Windows S-1... identifier. But there is a side effect of this trimming that may or may not be important to you. It is impossible to get back to the original SID you passed in because some of that data is gone. So if you create [the functions @eckes points out above](https://forum.mibuso.com/discussion/48606/find-sql-user-name-with-quot-windows-login-quot-sid), you will find slightly different output than you would expect:

```
SELECT name, sid, ws1 = dbo.fn_SIDToString(sid) 
  FROM sys.server_principals 
  WHERE name = N'Test';
```

Results:

```
name    sid                                   ws1
----    ----------------------------------    ------------------
Test    0x01050000000000051500000027035A18    S-1-5-21-408552231
```

That may or may not be acceptable. I do not know enough about Windows identifiers or about exactly why you want to create a SQL auth user that <s>is</s> *appears on first glance to be* mapped to one to know if this will meet your needs. But it gets past both the syntax error and the 28/16 issue.

---

Function I used, included here in case the link dies:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SIDToString]
(
  @BinSID AS VARBINARY(100)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS BEGIN

  IF LEN(@BinSID) % 4 <> 0 RETURN(NULL)

  DECLARE @StringSID VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @i AS INT
  DECLARE @j AS INT

  SELECT @StringSID = 'S-'
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, SUBSTRING(@BinSID, 1, 1)))) 
  SELECT @StringSID = @StringSID + '-'
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, SUBSTRING(@BinSID, 3, 6))))

  SET @j = 9
  SET @i = LEN(@BinSID)

  WHILE @j < @i
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @val BINARY(4)
    SELECT @val = SUBSTRING(@BinSID, @j, 4)
    SELECT @StringSID = @StringSID + '-'
      + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, REVERSE(CONVERT(VARBINARY, @val))))) 
    SET @j = @j + 4
  END
  RETURN ( @StringSID ) 
END
```

Comment: Hi Aaron. Regarding "_Windows identifiers or ... why you want to create a SQL auth user that is mapped to one_": by chopping off the last 12 bytes, there is no mapping between them. A SQL Server login's SID is merely an arbitrary 16-bytes. If those 16 bytes just happen to be the same as the first 16 bytes of a Windows SID, that is purely coincidence. A Windows SID cannot take on a reduced form in order to fit here, and even if it could, SQL Server isn't going to recognize it because supplying a password and SID means this is a SQL Server login. What the OP is trying to do can't be done.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Yes, how I meant to word that was "that seems to be mapped to one." My answer still serves to address the two other difficulties the OP was having around using a function/assignment in the CREATE LOGIN statement.

Comment: Ok, I was just making sure that it was clear that there was no _real_ connection between the modified SID and the original. And that if the original SID is of primary importance to the OP, then there is no workaround for that. But yes, the other points made here regarding syntax are still completely valid and helpful; I was not implying anything against any other aspect of this answer.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I tried to make it clear that truncating the value to make it fit was irreversibly losing data and not truly mapping, but I've updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: That is much clearer. Thanks for updating that. I have likewise updated my answer to clarify that I was not finding fault with how you solved the syntax error issue.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that [`CREATE LOGIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) accepts the SID value as a binary data type (emphasis mine):

> SID = sid
>
> Used to recreate a login. Applies to SQL Server
>   authentication logins only, not Windows authentication logins.
>   Specifies the SID of the new SQL Server authentication login. If this
>   option is not used, SQL Server automatically assigns a SID. The SID
>   structure depends on the SQL Server version. **SQL Server login SID: a
>   16 byte (binary(16)) literal value based on a GUID.** For example, SID =
>   0x14585E90117152449347750164BA00A7.

and

> ```
> DROP LOGIN TestLogin;  
> GO  
>
> CREATE LOGIN TestLogin   
> WITH PASSWORD = 'SuperSecret52&&', SID = 0x241C11948AEEB749B0D22646DB1A19F2;  
>
> SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'TestLogin';  
> GO
> ```

You can use [sp_help_revlogin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server) as an example of a common way to extract the binary SID value to generate `CREATE LOGIN` statements for existing logins - if you're working with a SQL Login. Seems like working with Windows accounts on a SQL Login is much trickier.

Comment: The problems: (1) In order to convert `N'S-1-5-21...'` to a `binary(16)` you need to perform an explicit conversion. (2) You can't perform such a conversion in `CREATE LOGIN`, and you can't use a variable, so you need dynamic SQL. (3) The conversion of `N'S-1-5-21...'` through `SID_BINARY()` returns a value that requires `binary(28)` to store correctly. If you try to pass this value into `CREATE LOGIN`, it gets rejected. Of course you can truncate to `binary(16)`, but then that doesn't store the full, original `N'S-1-5-21...'` value.

Comment: I've always just used [sp_help_revlogin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server) to get the clean binary value out. I spose you could hack together your own version if you had more robust needs, as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a script that calls it, I tried passing in the bytes as a parameter but that doesn't work either.

Comment: But sp_help_revlogin won't work if you don't already have a login. The OP is trying to create a login, so there's nowhere for the procedure to get a clean binary value from. So how did you translate `S-1-5-21-408552231-458724953-3089381293-513` to `binary(16)`?

Comment: Presumably the login existed *somewhere* and this SID value isn't random. I can't imagine a scenario where you'd need to define a SID that doesn't exist somwhere first, otherwise it'd be arbitrary. And even then, just create it once and then use the revlogin to generate the binary value for every automated `CREATE LOGIN` after.

Comment: The S-1... sid is from Windows, not SQL Server. Windows exposes them as an S-1... string, but SQL Server doesn't. In any case, you still can't cleanly translate an S-1 identifier from Windows (at least in the form the OP has) to a binary SID CREATE LOGIN will accept, because it's too big.

Comment: Ah you're right - totally glanced over that since he never called it out specifically.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: you cannot do this!

You are trying to create a SQL Server login (i.e. `WITH PASSWORD='Test123', SID=...` instead of `FROM ...`) but using a Windows SID (i.e. `0x01050000000000051500000027035A185996571BAD3724B801020000` instead of something along the lines of `0x4D50DEDF91DABA4595F121BBA9E8D4AF`). The documentation, quoted in [LowlyDBA's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/230434/30859) states:

> Applies to SQL Server authentication logins only, not Windows authentication logins.

And you did not get the SID that you are trying to use from a SQL Server login. There is no way to get this to work. The only reason that Aaron's approach *appears* to work (I am referring *only* to the SID that he is using; the dynamic SQL stuff is entirely correct) is by chopping off the excess bytes so that there are only 16 bytes left. But doing that makes the resulting value, `0x01050000000000051500000027035A18`, just as arbitrary as coming up with something on your own like `0x0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F10`. SQL Server login SIDs are just that: arbitrary identifiers. For example:

```
CREATE LOGIN [Whozitz] WITH PASSWORD='Test123', SID=0x0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F10;

SELECT SUSER_SNAME(0x0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F10);
-- Whozitz
```

Yet you were starting with `S-1-5-21-408552231-458724953-3089381293-513`, which is a meaningful identifier: not only does it reference a specific entity known to the OS (or some OS somewhere as it might have come from a different system), but those parts that are separated by the dashes in the string / SDDL form of the SID have meaning. The "1" is the version number and never changes. The "5" refers to the type of entity, I believe. And the rest of the segments are based on the type.

But, even if a SID did match entirely between SQL Server and the OS, the fact that the server principal / login is a SQL Server login means that there is no *actual* connection between the SID within SQL Server and the SID at the OS level.

If you want to create SQL Server logins based on the SIDs of logins that exist on other systems so that you can move databases over and not have to sync-up logins after the fact, or something like that, then you can only do that with existing **SQL Server** logins, not Windows logins.